# Redirect any page that has an .aspx ending to a new url

Tags: .htaccess

I am just learning how to edit .htaccess files.

Is there a way to tell it to redirect any page asking for a .aspx to go to a different url?

Example:
xxxxxx.com/login.aspx
redirect to: xxxxxx.net

There a lot of different pages since this was an old server move. I would love for a way to tell it to just redirect all that ask for a .aspx.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are all aspx pages going to the same destination? For example, example.com/login.aspx goes to example.net/ and example.com/blog.aspx also goes to example.net/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, am not an Apache hacker like RSE (the `Bastard Operator from Hell`),but I think this might help:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.aspx   $1.net   [L]
```

for more guidance from the master, look at the manual [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html)